# Is it possiable to set ExpiresDefault to a path ?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache

```
caches_pages index
```

will produce  `~/proj/public/index.html`   if we visit http://example.com/

Is it possiable to set ExpiresDefault to this index.html ?  such that if we visit  http://example.com/ again, browser will check expire date and won't to make a request.

I'm already tried:

```
 <Directory /home/rja/icross/public >
        AllowOverride all
        Options -MultiViews
        ExpiresActive On
        ExpiresDefault "access plus 30 minutes"
    </Directory>
```

I also see `Etag` and `Expires`  set correctly. However, my browser didn't to fetch a local cache, but still make a request and receive a 304 not modify.

Is ExpireActive only work with static file like .css ?